# Java - Error while executing command

Tags: java, terminal, execute

I am trying to execute a command in Terminal (on Ubuntu) and I can't seem to run the command `cd`, here is my code:

```
public static void executeCommand(String[] cmd) {
    Process process = null;

    System.out.print("Executing command \'");

    for (int i = 0; i < (cmd.length); i++) {

        if (i == (cmd.length - 1)) {
            System.out.print(cmd[i]);
        } else {
            System.out.print(cmd[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    System.out.print("\'...\n");

    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
        String line;

        System.out.println("Output: ");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        System.out.println("Error[s]: ");
        while ((line = err.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.err.println("An error occurred while executing command! Error:\n" + exc);
    }
}
```

(Just in case)
Here is how I call it:
`executeCommand(new String[]{ "cd", "ABC" });`

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you cant change java's default folder. its not vb6 ... you can get the same effect with more coding. for that need to tell us what you want to do after this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cd` is not an executable or script but rather a builtin command of the shell. Therefore you need:

```
executeCommand(new String[]{ "bash", "-c", "cd", "ABC" });
```

Although this shouldn't produce any error, it won't produce any output either. If multiple commands are required after this, it would be advisable to place *all comands* in a script file and call that from your Java application. This will not only make the code easier to read but also a re-compile won't be necessary should the commands change.